# Can we Use Idempotent Receiver against Jms message with ActiveMq

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am inserting readings in Data Base using WSO2Esb and WSO2DSS my inserting is working fine
while i am getting request reading from mobile side i need response with 200 and unique value
some times connection failed after inserting means insertion is over but client did'nt get response in that case mobile side client sending request one more time so again my proxy sending this request to database .So my database storing duplicate values for every 2 or 3 readings its totally unfair for  client for that i find a small solution
Using Idempotent service can we find solution for this

```
<!-- The example shows WSO2 ESB acting as an Idempotent Receiver -->
<definitions xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <proxy name="IdempotencyReceivingProxy">
        <target>
            <inSequence>
                <log level="full"/>
                <!-- Store all messages in an Jmsmemory message store -->
                <store messageStore="MyStore"/>
            </inSequence>
            <outSequence>
                <send/>
            </outSequence>
        </target>           
    </proxy>
    <!-- Further mediation of messages are done in this sequence -->
    <sequence name="next_seq">
        <send>
            <endpoint>
                <address uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService"/>
            </endpoint>
        </send>
    </sequence>
    <messageStore name="MyStore"/>
    <!-- Resequencing Processor takes the next sequence number and hand over to "next_seq" and preserve Idempotency -->
    <messageProcessor
            class="org.apache.synapse.message.processors.resequence.ResequencingProcessor"
            name="ResequencingProcessor" messageStore="MyStore"> 
        <parameter name="interval">2000</parameter>
        <!-- Takes the sequence number using Xpath -->
        <parameter name="seqNumXpath" xmlns:m0="http://services.samples" expression="substring-after(//m0:placeOrder/m0:order/m0:symbol,'-')"/>
        <parameter name="nextEsbSequence">next_seq</parameter>
        <parameter name="deleteDuplicateMessages">true</parameter> 
    </messageProcessor>
</definitions>
```

for this i followed this link http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/IntegrationPatterns/Idempotent+Receiver
Is it suitable for my requirement

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this would suit your requirement. What the resequencing processor does is, order the messages according to the number in `seqNumXpath` property. So the messages should include a number and you should obtain this number using a xpath expression. When `deleteDuplicateMessages` parameter is set to true, it will delete duplicate messages that have the same sequence number as obtained from `seqNumXpath` parameter.

In your case you can use a [store and forward](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB470/Store+and+Forward+Using+JMS+Message+Stores) scenario to prevent client having to send multiple requests. Set `FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED` property to true in your proxy service to always return 202 response to client. Then message will be stored in msg store and will be forwarded using message processor.

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB470/Store+and+Forward+Using+JMS+Message+Stores
http://wso2.com/library/articles/2011/10/implementing-store-forward-messaging-patterns-wso2esb-part-1

Comment: But After every message processing the message processor have been deactivate automatically if one more message will come to hit this message process how it will process

Comment: The message processor will deactivate only if message sending failed. i.e. even after the maximum no. of retry attempts, it was unable to send the message to backend. If msg processor was deactivated you will have to re-activate it.

Comment: if all the messages have been succesfully delivered, it will not deactivate. It will stay active and will periodically look in the message store to see if any messages are available.

Comment: thanx for replay k i will do practically and get back to you

Answer (score 0):

Apache Camel has an idempotent consumer http://camel.apache.org/idempotent-consumer.html that uses a IdempotentRepository to see if it has been seen before; if it has, the message is consumed; if its not, then the message is processed and the ID is added to the repository. Take a look at http://camel.apache.org/sql-component.html particularly section 'Using the JDBC based idempotent repository'. This is exactly what we need. Because in our case the duplicate messages can arrive even days later ( offline clients e.g. mobile devices) but each message has a UUID field which can be used to detect duplicates.

Is there a similar implementation available in wso2esb? If yes any pointers to the documentation? If no what are our alternatives to get this behaviour while using wso2esb?